# Cannot receive gstreamer UDP Stream from OpenCV Gstreamer

Tags: python, opencv, udp, gstreamer, video-capture

I'm working on Gazebo Sim which uses 'Gstreamer Plugin' to stream Camera Video via UDP. Simulation is started on Ubuntu 18.04.

There is some resources to understand backend of this structer.
[Gazebo Simulation PX4 Guide](https://dev.px4.io/v1.9.0/en/simulation/gazebo.html)

And they mentions how to create pipeline:

> The video from Gazebo should then display in QGroundControl just as it
>   would from a real camera.
>
> It is also possible to view the video using the Gstreamer Pipeline.
>   Simply enter the following terminal command:

```
gst-launch-1.0  -v udpsrc port=5600 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' \
! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink fps-update-interval=1000 sync=false
```

And it works well on terminal. I read these questions:

[using gstreamer with python opencv to capture live stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879501/using-gstreamer-with-python-opencv-to-capture-live-stream)

[Write in Gstreamer pipeline from opencv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544877/write-in-gstreamer-pipeline-from-opencv-in-python)

So then, I tried to implement this pipeline into opencv by using following lines:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('udpsrc port=5600 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink fps-update-interval=1000 sync=false', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
    #video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,3)
    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()
```

But it's only giving error:

***Could not open video***

And I tried different variations of this pipeline in opencv but None of them helped me.

Comment: I found useful code which is directly run on my case:
https://gist.github.com/patrickelectric/443645bb0fd6e71b34c504d20d475d5a


But I just want to use single line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works without errors:

```
# Read video
video = cv2.VideoCapture("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

I think decode option wasn't true.

Comment: Indeed the `avdec_h264` argument is either not supported or not working.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your pipeline provides no way for OpenCV to extract decoded video frames from the pipeline. This is because all frames go to the `autovideosink` element at the end which takes care of displaying the frames on-screen. Instead, you should use the `appsink` element, which is made specifically to allow applications to receive video frames from the pipeline.

```py
video = cv2.VideoCapture(
    'udpsrc port=5600 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264"'
    ' ! rtph264depay'
    ' ! avdec_h264'
    ' ! videoconvert'
    ' ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: That's the good point but still getting "Could not open video" when tried. Perhaps there is another issue on the pipeline. The link that below question in the comment works well but I think it's workaround for the issue. Maybe you can check the code for useful pipeline.

Comment: This pipeline works for me using your code and an RTP server set up with this command: "gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5600". You could try setting the GST_DEBUG environment variable to "3" and looking at the logs for error messages.

Comment: Maybe the pipeline that you used can be run without error. I'm using embedded gstream plugin so I can't be able to change debug mode or another function.
[Gstream Source](https://dev.px4.io/v1.9.0/en/simulation/gazebo.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your OpenCV has Gstreamer support by

```py
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

There should be

```
Video I/O:
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
    Intel Media SDK:             YES (/mnt/nfs/msdk/lin-18.4.1/lib64/libmfx.so)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code but did not work.
I also tried a different pipeline. Below are my terminal pipelines:

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v realsensesrc serial=$rs_serial timestamp-mode=clock_all enable-color=true ! rgbddemux name=demux demux.src_depth ! queue ! colorizer near-cut=300 far-cut=3000 ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host=192.168.100.80 port=9001
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)RGB, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1280, height=(string)720, payload=(int)96" ! rtpvrawdepay ! videoconvert ! queue ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
```

I can see the video using the above terminal pipeline in the receiver.
BUT when I converted it to python code, the output is:

**Could not open Video**

**gst_receiver.py**

```
import cv2
import sys

video = cv2.VideoCapture(
    'udpsrc port=9001 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW,'
    'sampling=(string)RGB, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1280, height=(string)720, payload=(int)96'
    ' ! rtpvrawdepay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! queue ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

# video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE,3)
# Exit if video not opened.
if not video.isOpened():
    print("Could not open Video")
    sys.exit()

# Read first frame.
ok, frame = video.read()
if not ok:
    print('Cannot read Video file')
    sys.exit()
```

**System:**

```
Sender-PC = Ubuntu 18.04
Receiver-PC = Windows 10
Python = 3.7.9
OpenCV = 4.5.5
```